# Set range for entire sheet for vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to do vLookup. For Vlookup syntax, it would be: VLOOKUP( value, table, index_number, [approximate_match] ) For the table I want to select the whole sheet, however I dun know where does the row ends for the data. How do I set the range for entire sheet till the unknown rows. So as to the codes below: 
**Sheet4.range("D1:Y14945")** It would be Y unknown as I don't know where the row ends. Thanks for your help in advance :)

```
Dim look As Variant
Dim x As Integer
x = 2
Sheet1.range("N2").Select
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
look = Sheet1.Cells(x, 14).Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(look, 
Sheet4.range("D1:Y14945"), 21, False)
Sheet1.Cells(x, 15).Value = result
x = x + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a reference without row numbers:

```
Sheet4.range("D:Y")
```